# Maximum over 7 columns in Quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I have a very simple problem, but unable to find a way to solve it in Quicksight.
I have data in the below form.I just want to compare the different columns(marks of different weeks) and print out the highest in a new column.
I have tried using the "Max" function, but seems like we can use it only for a specific column,

[image]

The output should look like:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that we can do aggregate functions across columns like in excel we can do max over range e.g. `=max(c1:c5)`

I have this work-around, given columns are not too many.

```
ifelse(
marks_week1>marks_week2, 
    ifelse(marks_week1>marks_week3, 
        ifelse(marks_week1>marks_week4, 
            ifelse(marks_week1>marks_week5, marks_week1, marks_week5), 
            ifelse(marks_week4>marks_week5, marks_week4, marks_week5)), 
        ifelse(marks_week3>marks_week4, 
            ifelse(marks_week3>marks_week5, marks_week3, marks_week5), marks_week4))
, ifelse(marks_week2>marks_week3, 
    ifelse(marks_week2>marks_week4, 
        ifelse(marks_week2>marks_week5, marks_week2, marks_week5), 
        ifelse(marks_week4>marks_week5,marks_week4, marks_week5)), 
    ifelse(marks_week3>marks_week4, 
        ifelse(marks_week3>marks_week5,marks_week3, marks_week5), 
        ifelse(marks_week4>marks_week5,marks_week4,marks_week5)))
)
```

[image]

Also [posted](https://community.amazonquicksight.com/t/function-to-calculate-aggregate-over-a-range-of-columns-same-as-in-excel-max-c1-c5/4140) on quicksight community as feature request or provide insight in case this exists already.